# woocommerce category wrong class name

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

output of woocommerce category listing(same in products listing) looks like this:

```
<li class="product-category product first"></li>
<li class="product-category product"></li>
<li class="product-category product"></li>
<li class="product-category product last"></li> // this shouldn't have class last
<li class="product-category product first"></li> // it should be the last one, but it has class first and it should have the class last
```

Does anyone know where can be a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is found within templates/content-product_cat.php. You can look into that file to see what logic was used and try to figure it out from there. It looks to me like it's basing it on a 4 column layout. After the fourth item, it'll name the 5th item as "first" again. Does that make sense? So 4 items per each row.

```
<li class="product-category product first"></li>
<li class="product-category product"></li>
<li class="product-category product"></li>
<li class="product-category product last"></li>


<li class="product-category product first"></li>
<li class="product-category product"></li>
<li class="product-category product"></li>
<li class="product-category product last"></li>


<li class="product-category product first"></li>
<li class="product-category product"></li>
<li class="product-category product"></li>
<li class="product-category product last"></li>
```